# Generating observations for non existing observations

Tags: sas, missing-data

I'm currently facing a problem in SAS. I'm writing my master thesis on occupational injuries and the wage loss inflicted by such an accident. I'm in possession of a data set with the monthly wage information for a given population. The dataset contains a specific identifier for each individual and also a range of background information like education, gender etc. If an individual has received a wage payment for a specific month he or she is in my data set for that specific month with the above-mentioned information. If the person has not been received a wage payment for a specific month (ex. due to unemployment, holiday, sickness etc), that person is not found in my data set for that specific month - even though the person may have received wage payment both in a prior month and also in a later month. So, for instance, a person who has worked a whole year has 12 observations in the dataset. If someone for some reason has not worked for 2 months, that person only has 10 observations.

I will most likely get a positive bias in my estimates if I don't take care of this issue. A person might suffer from an occupational injury in a given month and then return the month after, the month that the person is absent due to sickness should constitute a wage payment of zero but still contain the "background" information.

I have uploaded an example of the dataset, which can be found here:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/0zkr0430menotdf/Data.xlsx?dl=0

The data contains three individuals (1,2,3) with wage information, education group, gender. The person with the identifier 2 don't have not received a payment for month 8 and therefore don't have any observation for that month.

I don't know, how to make an SAS program, that would fill in the information for that person. I would like to make a new observation for month 8 for person 2 with a wage payment of zero but with the lagged information on the other variables from the prior month. In my original dataset, I have many several thousand people, where some potential could have multiple non-existing wage information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest approach is to build a `master` table that will contain every single combination of months and individual if your data were perfect. Once you have this dataset then you left join your *faulty* real data to get the full view regardless of missing data.

No need for lagging info as all columns will be there regardless.

Here is a dummy example (I call users instead of individuals)

```
/* table with 1-12 that represents months ids*/
data months(drop=i);
do i=1 to 12;
 month=i;
 output;
end;
run;
/* table with unique user ids*/
    data users;
user_id = 1000;gender='M';output;
user_id = 1001;gender='F';output;
run;

/* Your data*/
data my_data;
input user_id month salary;
cards;
1001 1 1500
1001 2 1500
1001 3 1500
1001 4 1500
1001 5 1500
1001 6 1500
1001 7 1500
1001 8 1500
1001 9 1500
1001 10 1500
1001 11 1500
1001 12 1500
1000 1 800
1000 2 800
1000 3 800
1000 4 800
;
run;

/* Step1: Build a full combination of (cartesian join) of months & users
  In this case is 12 months x 2 users = 24 records
*/
proc sql;
create table master_tbl as
    select * from months, users;
quit;

/* Step2: Left join your 'faulty' data against the master table to get a full view
for each user */

proc sql;
create table full_view as
Select t1.*, t2.salary from master_tbl t1 left join my_data t2
                            on t1.user_id = t2.user_id and
                               t1.month = t2.month;
quit;
```

The `full_view` data set will contain both non-missing and missing cases. You can detect missing cases when the salary information is missing.

Note: If you think your `wage` variable is also faulty then create a dummy flag in your data (f=1) and bring it in the `full_view` dataset to highlight missing data.

**EDIT 1:**
For replacing data you can do:

```
data full_view;
 set full_view;
 if salary = . then do;
   salary = 0;
   salary_ind = (salary = 0); /*Dummy to keep track of what you have imputed*/
end;
run;
```

Hope it helps

Comment: just added the extra bit for imputing missing values

Comment: also add gender to users table

Comment: Thanks a lot, Alton! I will try that! I didn't think of going that way about it.

Comment: No problem - If you're happy with my answer please accept it

Answer (score 1):

Quite similar to Altons' solution, one difference being that I replace missing values of wage in a PROC SQL step.

```
/*Load the data*/
PROC SQL;
    CREATE TABLE have AS 
        SELECT t1.Identifier, 
            t1.Month, 
            t1.Wage, 
            t1.'education category'n, 
            t1.gender
        FROM WORK.DATA t1
            ORDER BY identifier, month;
QUIT;


/*Create a dataset with 12 observations of each id.*/
data a;
    do i=1 to 3;
        do j=1 to 12;
            identifier=i;
            month=j;
            output;
        end;
    end;

    drop i j;
run;


/*Merge the dataset above with the original dataset, replacing missing values of wage with 0.*/
proc sql;
    create table ab as
        select a.*, coalesce(b.wage,0) as wage, b.'education category'n, b.gender
            from a
                left join have as b on a.identifier=b.identifier and a.month=b.month;
quit;


/*Use the update statement to carry forward previous non-missing values.*/
data want;
    update a (obs=0) ab;
    by identifier;
    output;
run;
```

Comment: Really clean solution! I like the nested loops in data a;